# Como atribuir uma EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING a uma tabela temporária

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

É possível no mesmo script criar uma tabela temporária a partir de um execução como essa?

```
        --****************************EMPRESA******************************
 if(Object_id('tempdb..#TBEmpresa') is not null)
    drop table #TBEmpresa
go  
 CREATE TABLE #TBEmpresa(
 EmpresaID int null,
 Empresa   varchar(50) null
 )
 go 
 insert into #TBEmpresa (EmpresaID, Empresa) values (1,'Vivo')
 insert into #TBEmpresa (EmpresaID, Empresa) values (2,'TIM')
 insert into #TBEmpresa (EmpresaID, Empresa) values (3,'Claro')
 go

 --*****************************SERVICOS***************************
if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBServico') is not null)
    drop table #TBServico
go
create table #TBServico(
ServicoID        int null,
DescricaoServico varchar(50) null
)
go

insert into #TBServico (ServicoID, DescricaoServico) values (1, 'Serviço de Dados')
insert into #TBServico (ServicoID, DescricaoServico) values (2, 'Serviço de TV')
insert into #TBServico (ServicoID, DescricaoServico) values (3, 'Servico de Internet')
insert into #TBServico (ServicoID, DescricaoServico) values (4, 'Servico de Voz')
insert into #TBServico (ServicoID, DescricaoServico) values (5, 'Servico de PABX')
go

--**********************SERVIÇO X EMPRESA *******************************
if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBServicoEmpresa') is not null)
    drop table #TBServicoEmpresa
go
create table #TBServicoEmpresa(
TBServicoEmpresaID int null,
TBEmpresaId        int null,
TBServicoId        int null
)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 1,1,1)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 2,1,2)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 3,1,3)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 4,1,4)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 5,1,5)

insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 6,2,1)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 7,2,2)

insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 8,2,3)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values ( 9,2,4)
insert into #TBServicoEmpresa (TBServicoEmpresaID, TBEmpresaId, TBServicoId) values (10,2,5)

--**********************PROCESSAMENTO************************************
if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBProcessamento') is not null)
    drop table #TBProcessamento
go
create table #TBProcessamento(
ProcessamentoID int null,
DataProcesso    DateTime null
)
go
insert into #TBProcessamento (ProcessamentoID, DataProcesso) values (1, '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBProcessamento (ProcessamentoID, DataProcesso) values (2, '2017-06-23 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBProcessamento (ProcessamentoID, DataProcesso) values (3, '2017-06-24 00:00:00.000')
--***********************GRADE********************************************************************
if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBGrade') is not null)
    drop table #TBGrade
go
create table #TBgrade(
GradeId         int null,
EmpresaId       int null,
ServicoId       int null,
ProcessamentoId int null,
Data            DateTime null,
Situacao        varchar(50) null
)
go
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 1,1,1,1, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 2,1,1,2, 'DESCONTINUADO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 3,1,1,3, 'EM PROCESSO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 4,1,1,4, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 5,1,1,5, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')

insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 6,1,2,1, 'DESCONTINUADO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 7,1,2,2, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')

insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 8,1,3,3, 'DESCONTINUADO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values ( 9,1,3,4, 'EM PROCESSO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
insert into #TBGrade (GradeId, ProcessamentoId, EmpresaId, ServicoId, Situacao, Data) values (10,1,3,5, 'EM PROCESSO', '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000')
go
---*************************************************************************************************************************************

if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBResultado') is not null)
    drop table #TBResultado
go

select GRD.ProcessamentoId, EMP.EmpresaID, EMP.Empresa, SRV.ServicoID, SRV.DescricaoServico, GRD.Situacao, GRD.Data
into #TBResultado
from #TBEmpresa as EMP
    inner join #TBgrade as GRD
        on GRD.EmpresaID = EMP.EmpresaID
    inner join #TBServicoEmpresa as SRVEMP
        on GRD.EmpresaId = SRVEMP.TBEmpresaId
    inner join #TBServico as SRV
        on SRV.ServicoID = GRD.ServicoId
GROUP BY GRD.ProcessamentoId, EMP.EmpresaID, EMP.Empresa, SRV.ServicoID, SRV.DescricaoServico, GRD.Situacao, GRD.Data

DECLARE @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @COLUNAS = ''
SELECT @COLUNAS = COALESCE(@COLUNAS + '[' + (CAST(DescricaoServico AS NVARCHAR(255))) + '],','')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DescricaoServico FROM #TBResultado) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS

SET @COLUNAS = LEFT (@COLUNAS, LEN(@COLUNAS)-1)
DECLARE @SQLSTRING NVARCHAR(1200);

SET @SQLSTRING = N'SELECT * FROM('+
                                'SELECT '+
                                'ProcessamentoId, '+
                                'EmpresaID, '+
                                'Empresa, '+
                                'ServicoID, '+
                                'DescricaoServico, '+
                                'Situacao,  '+
                                'Convert(varchar(10), Data,103) as [DATA] '+
                                'FROM #TBResultado) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS '+
                'PIVOT(MAX(Situacao) FOR DescricaoServico IN('+@COLUNAS+')) AS PivotTable '+
                'ORDER BY DATA DESC;'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING
```

Preciso jogar o resultado dessa execução em uma tabela temporária, algo assim:

```
    insert into #tab2
    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING
```

para manipular os dados.

Comment: A execução do INSERT na tabela #tab2 está dentro ou fora do procedimento?  // A tabela #tab2 é declarada dentro ou fora do procedimento?

Comment: @José Diz desculpe-me pela demora em responder, inicialmente a execução do INSERT seria dentro do procedimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você declarar a tabela temporária em contexto externo ao procedimento, ela é visível no procedimento e também no comando SQL dinâmico executado dentro do procedimento. Você deve executar o INSERT dentro do comando SQL dinâmico. Desta forma, ao terminar a execução do procedimento, a tabela temporária estará com as informações inseridas e poderá ser manipulada.

A explicação detalhada você encontra no capítulo 9 do livro `Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming`.

---

**AMPLIAÇÃO DA RESPOSTA**

> > Preciso jogar o resultado dessa execução em uma tabela temporária, algo assim:
> >         `insert into #tab2`
> >         `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING`
> >     para manipular os dados.

Como comentado no texto inicial desta resposta, *Se você declarar a tabela temporária em contexto externo ao procedimento, ela é visível no procedimento e também no comando SQL dinâmico executado dentro do procedimento.*. Ou seja, basta criar a tabela temporária #TBResultado antes de executar o comando SQL dinâmico. Entretanto, após analisar o código acrescentado posteriormente pelo autor do tópico, percebe-se que a estrutura completa da tabela temporária não é conhecida previamente, possuindo número de colunas variável (depende da quantidade de linhas da tabela TBServico). Para contornar este fato, a estrutura básica da tabela #TBResultado é criada usando comando SQL estático e, através de comando SQL dinâmico, são acrescentadas as colunas variáveis.

Eis sugestão de código para obter o relatório.

```
-- código #1 v3

--==========
 -- cria a tabela temporária para armazenar resultado da consulta dinâmica
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#TBResultado', 'U') is not null
  DROP TABLE #TBResultado;

CREATE TABLE #TBResultado (
   ProcessamentoID int not null,
   DataProc date not null,
   EmpresaID int not null,
   Empresa varchar(50) not null
);

-- monta nome das colunas para a consulta e comando de alteração da tabela #TBResultado
declare @comandoSQL varchar(8000);
set @comandoSQL= '';

declare @colID varchar(200), @colDescID varchar(4000);
set @colID= '';
set @colDescID= '';

SELECT @colID+= '[' + cast(ServicoID as varchar(3)) + '],',
       @colDescID+= '[' + cast(ServicoID as varchar(3)) + '] as [' + 
                     cast(ServicoID as varchar(3)) + ' - ' + DescricaoServico + '], ',
       @comandoSQL+= 
          'ALTER TABLE #TBResultado ADD [' + 
          cast(ServicoID as varchar(3)) + ' - ' + 
          DescricaoServico + '] varchar(50); '
  from TBServico
  order by DescricaoServico;
set @colID= left(@colID, len(@colID)-1);
set @colDescID= left(@colDescID, len(@colDescID)-1);  

-- acrescenta, usando comando SQL dinâmico, as colunas de serviço
--PRINT @comandoSQL;
EXECUTE (@comandoSQL);

-- monta comando SQL dinâmico
set @comandoSQL= 
  'with cteResultado as ( ' +
  'SELECT GRD.ProcessamentoId, GRD.Data, SRVEMP.EmpresaID, SRVEMP.ServicoID, GRD.Situacao ' +
  'from TBgrade as GRD ' +
  '    inner join TBServicoEmpresa as SRVEMP on SRVEMP.ServicoEmpresaId = GRD.ServicoEmpresaId ' +
  '    inner join TBProcessamento as PRC on PRC.ProcessamentoId = GRD.ProcessamentoId ' +
  '), ' +
  'cteP as ( ' +
  'SELECT ProcessamentoID, Data, EmpresaID, ' + @colID +
  '  from cteResultado ' +
  '       pivot (max(Situacao) for ServicoID in (' + @colID + ')) as P ' +
  ') ' +
  'INSERT into #TBResultado ' +
  '  SELECT P.ProcessamentoID, P.Data, ' +
  '         P.EmpresaID, EMP.Empresa, ' + @colID +
  '    from cteP as P ' +
  '      inner join TBEmpresa as EMP on EMP.EmpresaId = P.EmpresaId;';

-- executa a consulta via comando SQL dinâmico
--PRINT @comandoSQL
EXECUTE (@comandoSQL)

-- exibe conteúdo da tabela #TBResultado
SELECT *
  from #TBResultado;
```

---

Observe que a declaração das tabelas e os comandos de carga foram revisados, com o acréscimo de integridades referenciais, chaves primárias etc.

```
-- código #2
set nocount on

if OBJECT_ID('TBGrade') is not null
    drop table TBGrade;

if OBJECT_ID('TBServicoEmpresa', 'U') is not null
    drop table TBServicoEmpresa;

if Object_id('TBEmpresa') is not null
    drop table TBEmpresa;

if Object_id('TBServico') is not null
    drop table TBServico;

if (OBJECT_ID('TBProcessamento') is not null)
    drop table TBProcessamento;
go

       --****************************EMPRESA******************************
 CREATE TABLE TBEmpresa(
    EmpresaID int not null primary key,
    Empresa   varchar(50) not null
 )
 go 
 insert into TBEmpresa (EmpresaID, Empresa) values 
    (1,'Vivo'), (2,'TIM'), (3,'Claro');
 go

 --*****************************SERVICOS***************************
create table TBServico(
   ServicoID        int not null primary key,
   DescricaoServico varchar(50) not null
)
go

insert into TBServico (ServicoID, DescricaoServico) values 
   (1, 'Serviço de Dados'),
   (2, 'Serviço de TV'),
   (3, 'Servico de Internet'),
   (4, 'Servico de Voz'),
   (5, 'Servico de PABX');
go

--**********************SERVIÇO X EMPRESA *******************************
create table TBServicoEmpresa(
   ServicoEmpresaID int not null primary key,
   EmpresaId        int not null references TBEmpresa,
   ServicoId        int not null references TBServico
);

insert into TBServicoEmpresa (ServicoEmpresaID, EmpresaId, ServicoId) values 
  (1,1,1), (2,1,2), (3,1,3), (4,1,4), (5,1,5), (6,2,1),
  (7,2,2), (8,2,3), (9,2,4), (10,2,5);


  --**********************PROCESSAMENTO************************************
create table TBProcessamento(
   ProcessamentoID int not null primary key,
   DataProcesso    Date not null
);
go

set dateformat ymd;
insert into TBProcessamento (ProcessamentoID, DataProcesso) values 
     (1, '2017-06-22'),
     (2, '2017-06-23'),
     (3, '2017-06-24');


--***********************GRADE********************************************************************

create table TBgrade(
   GradeId         int not null primary key,
   ServicoEmpresaId int not null references TBServicoEmpresa,
   ProcessamentoId int not null references TBProcessamento,
   Data            Date not null,
   Situacao        varchar(50) not null
);
go

insert into TBGrade (GradeId, ServicoEmpresaId, ProcessamentoId, Situacao, Data) values 
   (1,1,1, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22'),
   (2,2,1, 'DESCONTINUADO', '2017-06-22'),
   (3,3,1, 'EM PROCESSO', '2017-06-22'),
   (4,4,1, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22'),
   (5,5,1, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22'),
   (6,6,1, 'DESCONTINUADO', '2017-06-22'),
   (7,7,1, 'EM USO', '2017-06-22'),
   (8,8,1, 'DESCONTINUADO', '2017-06-22'),
   (9,9,1, 'EM PROCESSO', '2017-06-22'),
   (10,10,1, 'EM PROCESSO', '2017-06-22');   
go
```

Comment: Olá @José Diz não consegui adaptar o exemplo ao meu script, eu editei o meu post e enriqueci a query, você poderia me dar mais exemplo de como implementar ?

Comment: @Front: Ampliei o texto da resposta, já considerando o novo texto da pergunta. Agora o resultado final é gravado na tabela temporária, conforme solicitado.